# .type() method vs type() function in Python

Tags: python

Just trying to figure out what the difference is between .type() method and type() function. To me, I don't see why they are returning different outputs although they seem to be doing the same thing (ie. determining the type of the object)

```
x = 1
print(x.type())

returns: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'type'
```

whereas

```
x = 1
print(type(x))

returns: <class 'int'>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: the difference is - one exists and returns type of object - another does not exist - what basically error message tells to you...

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a .type() method for int. That is what the first message is saying. So use the second version and you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

[type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) is a built-in function, which returns the type of the object you pass in as the parameter.

When you try to call x.type(), what you're attempting to do is call the type() method on an int object, and that simply does not exist. Hence the attribute error.

Note, to check the attributes that actually exist for x, you could use dir(x)

Answer (score 0):

The `type(object)` function returns the class an object is an instance of. For example, `type(42)` tells you that `42` is an `int`.

If you were to make a custom class, using `type(object)` where `object` is an instance of the new class would return the class itself.

You can also look into using the `isinstance` function, which is widely considered to be more Pythonic.

The `.type()` method doesn’t exist, at lease not for `int`s. That’s why you get an error there.